# PHP – Can't get left join tables to echo

Tags: php, html, mysql, join

Hi I am fairly new at PHP and I am trying to join 2 table and echo the result in and HTML table.

The 2 tables are “client” and “job” I want to echo the clients name using the clients id stored in in the job table with the column name “client_id”. Here’s my code not sure what I am doing wrong. Thanks for the help. I am open to better ways of doing this.

```
        $result = mysql_query("SELECT `id`, `job_name`, `client.id`, `job_day`, `s_t`, `e_t`, `status` FROM job LEFT JOIN client ON job.client_id = client.id");
        if (!$result) {
            die("Query to show fields from table failed");
        }

        $fields_num = mysql_num_fields($result);

        echo "<table class='table table-bordered table-striped mb-none' id='datatable-tabletools' data-swf-path='assets/vendor/jquery-datatables/extras/TableTools/swf/copy_csv_xls_pdf.swf' >";
        // printing table headers
        echo "<thead>";
        echo "<th>#</th>";
        echo "<th>Job Name</th>";
        echo "<th>Client Name</th>";
        echo "<th>Job Day</th>";
        echo "<th>Start Time</th>";
        echo "<th>End Time</th>";
        echo "<th>Status</th>";
        echo "</thead>";
        // printing table rows
        while($row = mysql_fetch_row($result))
        {
            echo "<tbody>";
            echo "<tr>";

            echo "<td><a href='job_view.php?job=" . $row['0'] . "'>See</a></td>";
            echo "<td>$row[1]</td>";
            echo "<td>$row[2]</td>";
            echo "<td>$row[3]</td>";
            echo "<td>$row[4]</td>";
            echo "<td>$row[5]</td>";
            echo "<td>$row[6]</td>";

            echo "</tr>";
            echo "</tbody>";

        }
        mysql_free_result($result);
        ?>
        </table>
    </div>
</section>
```

Comment: You have `client.id` instead of `client`.`id`. Hmm doesn't come through very well. You need to put tildes inbetween client and id eg 'client'.'id' where you replace ' with `

Answer (score 0):

You need to put parenthesis around your `ON` clause, and specify ambiguous columns (for sure `id`, could be others as well), and you need to put backticks around both the table and the column name, individually (not `client.id` but `client`.`id`):

```
SELECT `job`.`id`, `job_name`, `client`.`id`, `job_day`, `s_t`, `e_t`, `status` 
FROM job 
LEFT JOIN client ON (job.client_id = client.id)
```

Comment: Hi Dave, I updated the code but I still get "Query to show fields from table failed". Here's what I updated.

                $result = mysql_query("SELECT `job`.`id`, `job_name`, `client`.`id`, `job_day`, `s_t`, `e_t`, `status` FROM job LEFT JOIN client ON (job.client_id = client.id)");
                if (!$result) {
                    die("Query to show fields from table failed");
                }

Comment: Why don't you do `if (!$result) { die('Invalid query: ' . mysql_error()); }` so you can see what it says the error is?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT `id`, `job_name`, `client`.`id`, `job_day`, `s_t`, `e_t`, `status` FROM job LEFT JOIN client ON job.client_id = client.id
```

Instead of selecting `client`.`id`, why don't you select `client`.`name` or whatever the column name is.